# sg-cdb Java library for working with cdb database

Tags: cdb

I have downloaded sg-cdb Java library from http://www.strangegizmo.com/products/sg-cdb/ and included it in my project. I'm trying to read CDB database with the following code:

```
import com.strangegizmo.cdb.Cdb;
import com.strangegizmo.cdb.CdbElement;
import java.util.Enumeration;

class Start
{ 
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Cdb cdbFile = null;
        try{
            cdbFile = new Cdb("basefile.cdb");
        }catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        try
        {
            Enumeration em = cdbFile.elements("basefile.cdb");
            while(em.hasMoreElements())
            {
                CdbElement cdbElt = (CdbElement) em.nextElement();
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong that I'm getting the following exception message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid cdb format
    at com.strangegizmo.cdb.Cdb$1.nextElement(Cdb.java:358)
```

Can you provide any example of working with this library?

Thank you.

Comment: did you get solution for it ? I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of sg-cdb and can help you get going with the library.

The primary issue with your sample is that you have to "make" a CDB file before you can enumerate over the file's elements.  The portable way to do that is to generate a file in the [cdbmake/cdbdump format](http://cr.yp.to/cdb/cdbmake.html) and then use the static `CdbMake.make(...)` method to turn that file into a constant database.  You can then load that constant database with the `Cdb` class and query for keys, enumerate over values, etc.

sg-cdb supports another mechanism for creating constant databases, which is to construct an instance of the [`CdbMake`](https://github.com/malyn/sg-cdb/blob/master/java/com/strangegizmo/cdb/CdbMake.java) class directly, call `start(...)` to begin writing to the database, call `add(...)` to add keys to the database, and then call `finish()` when you are done writing keys.

Here is an update to your example that uses CdbMake.start/.add/.finish to generate a file and then enumerate over the file:

```java
import com.strangegizmo.cdb.Cdb;
import com.strangegizmo.cdb.CdbElement;
import com.strangegizmo.cdb.CdbMake;
import java.util.Enumeration;

class Start
{ 
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try{
            CdbMake maker = new CdbMake();
            maker.start("basefile.cdb");
            maker.add("one".getBytes(), "Hello".getBytes());
            maker.add("two".getBytes(), "Goodbye".getBytes());
            maker.finish();
        }catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        try
        {
            Enumeration em = Cdb.elements("basefile.cdb");
            while(em.hasMoreElements())
            {
                CdbElement cdbElt = (CdbElement) em.nextElement();
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Note that `elements(...)` is a static method on the `Cdb` class, so you do not need a `Cdb` instance in order to dump everything in the database.

In general my recommendation is that you ingest `cdbdump`-formatted files though.  You would get the same results if you run `cdbmake` (or the `cdb.make` utility that is included with sg-cdb) on the following text file:

```
+3,5:one->Hello
+3,7:two->Goodbye
```

One final note: creating a new instance of the `Cdb` class always succeeds (even if the file does not exist), because it is perfectly valid to have a file with no keys.  A `Cdb` instance initialized with a non-existent file (as you have done in your example) will correctly return null in response to every `find()` call.  `Cdb.enumerate(...)` is not quite as forgiving though and expects to be given the path to a valid CDB file, which is why you are getting that IllegalArgumentException.

Let me know if you need any additional information!

Comment: Hi Michael, It still does not work. I am getting the same exception. I am trying to read an external cdb file and the api says "invalid cdb format" although another tool is able to read the same file.